# JavaFX: How can I access a cotroller method from a normal java class?

Tags: java, logging, controller, javafx, textarea

I´m programming a Tool that should be able to continuously log Strings into a TextArea. The Controller Class has a simple method setText(); that will append strings to the TextArea. My Problem: I can´t really let the controller constantly watch at my logging class since that will just make the GUI unusable. The only solution in my eyes is to somehow get acces to the TextArea OR the setText() method outside of the controller. Is this possible and what do I have to do in my logging class to get acces to the controller methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why your controller should watch your logging class? Run up a separate thread for any time consuming work -- log directly from your new thread. You can access GUI components from any thread, but if you are using any GUI framework like JAVAFX, make sure to allow the GUI time to process your response with a run later type thing: As you can see, this won't affect your response times on GUI front end, providing you stay out of the event dispatch thread.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class LogThing extends Application {

private TextField textField;
private TextField textField2;
private Button clickMeBtn;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    primaryStage.setTitle("Logger!");
    textField = new TextField();
    textField2 = new TextField();
    clickMeBtn = new Button("Click me for time");
    clickMeBtn.setOnAction(e -> {
                textField2.setText(new Date().toString());
            });
    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    VBox vBox = new VBox();
    vBox.getChildren().addAll(textField2, clickMeBtn, textField);
    root.getChildren().add(vBox);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
    primaryStage.show();
    Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(new BackGroundTask(this));
}

public void logALine(String line) {
    textField.setText(line);
}

class BackGroundTask implements Runnable {

    private final LogThing logThing;
    private int i = 1;

    public backGroundTask(LogThing logThing) {
        this.logThing = logThing;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            for (i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            logThing.logALine("i : " + i);
                        }
                    });

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thats the solution I came up with last night, thanks for your input anyway! Marked your answer as the right one regardless.

Answer (score 0):

You should read about *javafx* properties. With *javafx* properties you can "observe" the value of an "external" property and bind it to a visual control. Also you should consider using a list control instead a `textarea`. Here is a short code snippet.

Model Class:

```
StringProperty someString = new SimpleStringProperty(""); // etc...
```

Controller Class:

```
textField.textProperty().bind(model.someStringProperty());
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/properties-binding-tutorial/binding.htm